# Is there a way in the Google Sheets API to access the script editor?

Tags: google-sheets-api

For example, I'd like to write a (Python, say) program that generates a Google sheet, then writes some custom .gs code into the Apps Script attached to that sheet, then writes values into the sheet itself using formulas defined in the Apps Script. What I currently do is use Tools > Script Editor, then manually copy-paste the relevant Apps Script code.

Comment: Unfortunately, Sheets API cannot manage Google Apps Script in the Spreadsheet. In that case, how about using Apps Script API? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned by @Tanaike, You can use [Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest) to add [container-bound script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound?hl=en).

### (OPTION 1: Writing the function manually in the script content)

**What to do:**

1. Create a [container-bound script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound?hl=en) using [projecs.create](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/create) method.

> To set a container-bound script, you need to assign the spreadsheet file id to the **parentId** parameter

**Sample Request Body:**

```
{
  "title": "new",
  "parentId": "spreadsheet file id"
}
```

2. Get the newly created container-bound **script id** in the [project response body](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects#Project) of [projecs.create](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/create) method.

**Sample Response Body:**

```
{
  "scriptId": "newly created script id",
  "title": "new",
  "parentId": "spreadsheet file id",
  "createTime": "2020-12-25T23:33:48.026Z",
  "updateTime": "2020-12-25T23:33:48.026Z"
}
```

3. Update the content of the newly created bound script using [projects.updateContent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/updateContent) method and include your function.

**Sample Request Body:**

```
{
  files: [{
      name: 'hello',
      type: 'SERVER_JS',
      source: 'function helloWorld() {\n  console.log("Hello, world!");\n}'
    }, {
      name: 'appsscript',
      type: 'JSON',
      source: "{\"timeZone\":\"America/New_York\",\"" +
      "exceptionLogging\":\"CLOUD\"}"
    }]
}
```

### (OPTION 2: Copy an existing script and paste it as bound script)

1. Create a [standalone script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone?hl=en) that will contain your custom functions.
2. Get the newly created standalone script project content using [projects.getContent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/getContent) which will return a [content resource](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/getContent#response-body)

> **scriptId** can be seen in your standalone script project under File -> Project Properties

3. Create a [container-bound script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound?hl=en) using [projecs.create](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/create) method.

> To set a container-bound script, you need to assign the spreadsheet file id to the **parentId** parameter

Sample Request Body:

```
{
  "title": "new",
  "parentId": "spreadsheet file id"
}
```

4. Get the newly created container-bound script id in the [project response body](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects#Project) of [projecs.create](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/create) method.

Sample Response Body:

```
{
  "scriptId": "newly created script id",
  "title": "new",
  "parentId": "spreadsheet file id",
  "createTime": "2020-12-25T23:33:48.026Z",
  "updateTime": "2020-12-25T23:33:48.026Z"
}
```

5. Update the content of the newly created bound script using [projects.updateContent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/updateContent) method.

**Use the [content resource](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/getContent#response-body) returned in Step 2 as the request body. Make sure to replace the script id based on the newly created bound script id that is obtained in Step 4.**

---

**Example Standalone Script:**

[image]

**Example Result of the Workaround:**

[image]

---

You can now use the custom function in the Google Sheets

[image]